# Android: How to list all data rows belonging to a specific RawContacts account in one query

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, contactscontract

I'm creating a contact app in android and I'm adding contacts to a specific account. How can I select all Data rows for all RawContacts belonging to this account in one query?
I know I can first select all RawContacts belonging to the account and then foreach _ID I could select all Data entries. But first of all that's really slow, but most important I want to get a cursor for all those Data rows so that I can provide this cursor to a CursorAdapter.

```
    Cursor rawCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
    RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {
            RawContacts.CONTACT_ID,
            RawContacts._ID,
        },
        RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?  AND " + RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ? ",
        new String[] {account_type, account_name},
        null);

while (rawCursor.moveToNext()) {
    long rawContactID = rawCursor.getLong(rawCursor.getColumnIndex(RawContacts._ID));
    Cursor dataCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
        Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] {
            Data._ID,
            Data.MIMETYPE,
            Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY,
            Data.DATA1,
            Data.DATA2,
            Data.DATA3,
        },
        Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
        new String[] {String.valueOf(rawContactID)},
        null);
}
```

Comment: We will need to see your current workings & code

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really don't think that my code will help answering this question but basically I would like to get this into one query:

Comment: I sure someone else have experienced this problem. Anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 0):

For now I solved this by first querying all raw_contacts and then using an IN statement in the selection. like:

```
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor idCursor = getRawContactsCursor(context, new String[]{RawContacts._ID}, account_name);
    try {
        while (idCursor.moveToNext()) {
            ids.add(idCursor.getString(idCursor.getColumnIndex(RawContacts._ID)));
        }
    } finally {
        idCursor.close();
    }

    String idSql = "?";
    for (int i = 1; i < ids.size(); i++) {
        idSql += ",?";
    }

    String whereSQL = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " IN (" + idSql + ")";
    String[] whereArgs = null;

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mimetype)) {
        whereSQL += " AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? ";
        ids.add(mimetype);
    }
    whereArgs = ids.toArray(new String[ids.size()]);

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            whereSQL,
            whereArgs,
            Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID);
    return cursor;
```

I just wonder what will happen when the number of raw_contacts becomes large enough. I'm guessing that having a thousand or more raw_contact id's will break stuff.